# DaisyUI modal does not exist on type Window of type globalThis

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, daisyui

I'm trying to import a dialog component from daisy ui but I'm getting the following error message:

```
Unsafe member access .showModal on an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
Unsafe return of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
Property 'my_modal_2' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)
```

I didn't tamper with the default code:

```
<button
              className="btn"
              onClick={() => window.my_modal_2.showModal()}
            >
              open modal
            </button>
            <dialog id="my_modal_2" className="modal">
              <form method="dialog" className="modal-box">
                <h3 className="text-lg font-bold">Hello!</h3>
                <p className="py-4">Press ESC key or click outside to close</p>
              </form>
              <form method="dialog" className="modal-backdrop">
                <button>close</button>
              </form>
            </dialog>
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example code is in javascript and consequently not type-safe in typescript which you use.

Try the following, which is a bit more verbose but should remove all ts errors:

```
<button
  className="btn"
  onClick={() => {
    if (document) {
      (document.getElementById('my_modal_2') as HTMLFormElement).showModal();
    }
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 6):

#### TL;DR **useRef**

```
const myModal = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null)

return (
   <>
     <dialog className='modal' ref={myModal}>
       ...
     </dialog>
     <button onClick={() => myModal.current?.showModal()}>...<button>
   </>
)
```

---

#### Long answer

Usually any time you want to access something related to the DOM or the window object, your first thought when using React should be Refs.

##### Here, React docs give you a nice list of when to use Refs:

https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#when-to-use-refs

Quoting the docs:

> Typically, you will use a ref when your component needs to “step outside” React and communicate with external APIs—often a browser API that won’t impact the appearance of the component.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `Next.js v13.4.19` with typescript and this worked for me:

You need to expand the global Window object like this:
***Note**: This makes the `my_modal_2` available in your whole project on the Window interface not just in your file

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    my_modal_2: HTMLFormElement;
  }
}
```

## Complete example:

```
"use client";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    my_modal_2: HTMLFormElement;
  }
}

type Props = {};

const ModalComponent = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <button className="btn" onClick={()=>window.my_modal_2.showModal()}>open modal</button>

      <dialog id="my_modal_2" className="modal">
        <form method="dialog" className="modal-box">
          <h3 className="font-bold text-lg">Hello!</h3>
          <p className="py-4">Press ESC key or click outside to close</p>
        </form>
        <form method="dialog" className="modal-backdrop">
          <button>close</button>
        </form>
      </dialog>
    </>
  );
};
```